# jQuery get data-parent value

Tags: jquery

I have some checkboxes that when one of them is checked returns a value stored in `data-parent`

The HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" data-parent="some-parent">
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function(event) {
    alert($(this).data(parent));
});
```

Here this returns `[object Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need quote `parent`:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function(event) {
    alert($(this).data("parent"));
});
```

single quotes are also fine.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `.checkbox` suppose to represent element(s) with classname `checkbox`.
Try using psuedo-selector

```
$(document).on('change', ':checkbox', function(event) { 
    alert($(this).data('parent'));
});
```